# will_paginate install timeout error when installing

Tags: will-paginate

Anyone having trouble trying to install the will_paginate plugin. When I try to install I get a timeout error. I have tried it a bunch of times with no luck.

rails plugin install svn://errtheblog.com/svn/plugins/will_paginate

> svn: Can't connect to host 'errtheblog.com': Operation timed out

Answer (score 0):

Oops for anyone trying to install the plugin and having trouble like me try installing the gem. https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Installation